# Split a data into subsets and apply a function to each subset.(Not the usual, quite challenging)

Tags: r

I have looked in plyr but what i am trying to achieve is quite different than the usual

```
Time               Criteria

17/05/2013 17:22   A
17/05/2013 17:23   A
17/05/2013 17:29   A
17/05/2013 17:22   B
17/05/2013 17:28   B
17/05/2013 17:29   B
25/05/2013 16:56   C
25/05/2013 16:56   C
```

I want to split this data by criteria. Then for each subset, iterate through the records and decide whether to keep that record or not if each record is less than 5mins away from last record.

Desired Result:

```
Time               Criteria  Keep

17/05/2013 17:22   A         T
17/05/2013 17:23   A         T
17/05/2013 17:29   A         F --> 29 is more than 5 mins from 23
17/05/2013 17:22   B         F --> Not keeping this because it is >5min from next record
17/05/2013 17:28   B         T 
17/05/2013 17:29   B         T
25/05/2013 16:56   C         T
25/05/2013 16:56   C         T
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1368782520, 1368782580, 1368782940, 
1368782520, 1368782880, 1368782940, 1369472160, 1369472160), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Singapore"), Criteria = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", 
"Criteria"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am not sure this is well-posed. Why would it not be the second `B` that is kicked out because it is more than `5` away from the first `B` and not the other way around?

Comment: I need to do this programmatically, as long as faced with the condition mentioned above, forsake the 1st row and keep trying with the next. that's why 17:22 is forsaken, 17:28, 17:29 are kept.

Comment: I was trying to work out why my solution was not giving the required result, and realised that your `Time` is not consistent between your demo data and the desired result...

Comment: sorry, the magic of copy&paste

Comment: Done, not sure if i did it correctly, i didn't know about dput until now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
ddply(dat, "Criteria", transform,
      Keep = c(FALSE, diff(Time) <= 5) |
             c(diff(Time) <= 5, FALSE))

#                  Time Criteria  Keep
# 1 2013-05-17 17:22:00        A  TRUE
# 2 2013-05-17 17:23:00        A  TRUE
# 3 2013-05-17 17:29:00        A FALSE
# 4 2013-05-17 17:22:00        B FALSE
# 5 2013-05-17 17:28:00        B  TRUE
# 6 2013-05-17 17:29:00        B  TRUE
# 7 2013-05-25 16:56:00        C  TRUE
# 8 2013-05-25 16:56:00        C  TRUE
```

I am not super familiar with diff dates, so you might have to be careful and find out if there is a way to make it systematically return the time difference in minutes (which is the case in this example though.)

Comment: If it's not too troublesome would you mind explaining to me how this works? c(FALSE, diff(Time) <= 5) | c(diff(Time) <= 5, FALSE) will end up with a vector length 2 how does it fit into 1 variable "Keep"?

Comment: It reads: "Keep me" if I am within five minutes of the previous one or (`|`) within five minutes of the next one. The first element does not have a previous one and the last element does not have a last one, hence the use of `c(FALSE,...)` and `c(...,FALSE)`.